# error[E0576]: cannot find associated type `RuntimeCall` in trait `pallet_nfts::Config`?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rust, substrate-node

"I'm developing a pallet called xnft for cross-chain NFT transfers. To achieve this, I have to utilize functions from the Frame NFT pallet and incorporate RuntimeCall in its configuration. However, I'm facing a challenge as I'm unable to modify the FRAME NFT pallet to include RuntimeCall in it.I am providing code snippet for this.

```
call: <T as pallet_nfts::Config>::RuntimeCall::from(pallet_nfts::Call::<
                        T,
                        I,
                    >::set_metadata {
                        collection: dest_collection_id,
                        item: dest_item_id,
                    })
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve it would be appreciated."

Comment: Try `<T as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeCall`, otherwise please post the full code.

Comment: I tried it earlier, it doesn't works.

Comment: Then please post the full code - or better, a link to the GitHub. Otherwise its not possible to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type RuntimeCall: From<pallet_nfts::Call<Self,I>> + Encode;
```

Structure your pallet's runtime call in the following manner.